# Creating new component for each Artist in a Music App (Similar to iTunes, Spotify, ect) -- Angular4

Tags: json, angular, angular-components, audio-player

So I am creating a music app clone of the Google All Access music web app using Angular 4.

So far, here is the data service I am using for the JSON data of all the artists, albums, ect (haven't filled it out yet with the correct data entirely lol):

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  constructor() { }

  data = {
    "artists": [
      {
        "artistName": "Lupe Fiasco",
        "artistsPicture": "../assets/artists-images/lupe.jpg",
        "genre": "Hip-Hop",
        "albums": [
          { "name": "Food & Liquor",
            "artistName": "Lupe Fiasco",
            "isExplicit": "true",
            "albumCover": "../assets/album-covers/f&l.jpg",
            "songs": {
              "name": "Kick, Push",
              "file": "mp3"
            },
          },
          { "name": "The Cool",
            "artistName": "Lupe Fiasco",
            "isExplicit": "true",
            "albumCover": "../assets/album-covers/thecool.jpeg",
            "songs": {
              "name": "Kick, Push",
              "file": "mp3"
            },

          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "artistName": "Flume",
        "artistsPicture": "../assets/artists-images/flume.jpg",
        "genre": "Electronic",
        "albums": [
          { "name": "Flume",
            "artistName": "Flume",
            "isExplicit": "true",
            "albumCover": "../assets/album-covers/flume.jpg",
            "songs": {
              "name": "Sleepless",
              "file": "mp3"
            }
          },
          { "name": "Skin",
            "artistName": "Flume",
            "isExplicit": "true",
            "albumCover": "../assets/album-covers/skin.png",
            "songs": {
              "name": "Sleepless",
              "file": "mp3"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "artistName": "Linkin Park",
        "artistsPicture": "../assets/artists-images/linkinpark.jpg",
        "genre": "Nu-Metal",
        "albums": [
          { "name": "Hybrid Theory",
            "artistName": "Linkin Park",
            "isExplicit": "true",
            "albumCover": "../assets/album-covers/meteora.jpg",
            "songs": [{"name": "Sleepless","file": "mp3"}]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "artistName": "Drake",
        "artistsPicture": "../assets/artists-images/drake.jpg",
        "genre": "Hip-Hop",
        "albums": [
          { "name": "Views",
            "artistName": "Drake",
            "isExplicit": "true",
            "albumCover": "../assets/album-covers/views.png",
            "songs": {
              "name": "Sleepless",
              "file": "mp3"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "artistName": "J.Cole",
        "artistsPicture": "../assets/artists-images/jcole.jpg",
        "genre": "",
        "albums": [
          { "name": "2014 Forest Hills Drive",
            "artistName": "J.Cole",
            "isExplicit": "true",
            "albumCover": "../assets/album-covers/fhd.jpg",
            "songs": {
              "name": "Sleepless",
              "file": "mp3"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "artistName": "Eminem",
        "artistsPicture": "../assets/artists-images/eminem.jpg",
        "genre": "Hip-Hop",
        "albums": [
          { "name": "Marshal Matthers LP",
            "artistName": "Eminem",
            "isExplicit": "true",
            "albumCover": "../assets/album-covers/mmlp.jpg",
            "songs": {
              "name": "Sleepless",
              "file": "mp3"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
    ]
  }


}
```

So here is what I am having a problem with. In the ARTIST section, the User would obviously be clicking on an artist to go to that specific artist page, where I would be displaying all the artists' albums, top songs, info, ect.

In my head I am like, oh man, I would have to create a new component for each artist? *darth vader voice* NNNoooOOOOOOoooOOoooOOO!!! With only 6 artists, It wouldn't be a problem. But when I am thinking about scalability.. that has to suck!

So is there any type of solution of routing to a component that has the info of the artist that is clicked?

Here is the AlbumsComponent in my app for what it is worth:

HTML:

```
<div class="card" *ngFor='let x of getAlbums'>
  <img src="{{x.albumCover}}" alt="">
  <div class="info">
    <p class="album-name">{{ x.name }}</p>
    <p class="artist-name">{{ x.artistName }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

ComponentTS:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from './../../data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-albums',
  templateUrl: './albums.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./albums.component.css']
})
export class AlbumsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  artistData = this.dataService.data.artists;

  albums: any[] = [];



 getAlbums = this.artistData.reduce(
   (acc: any, next: any) => {
     next.albums.forEach(album => {
       acc.push(album);
     });
   return acc;
 }, []);

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.getAlbums);

  }

}
```

Intuitively, I am thinking of maybe making a ArtistPageComponent, then somehow getting data to that component depending on that Artist.

Any help to at least put me in the right direction would help!

Comment: You answered your own question right at the end of your post :P You should have two separate `routes`, one for the `ArtistList` and one for the `ArtistDetail`.  and have each `component` handle only what it needs to, i.e. `ArtistList` gets the entire list and displays a link to the individual `ArtistDetail` page which would take an id as a param, and then you can dynamically display the `ArtistDetail`

Comment: So for an artistID, would i make a property in the JSON for each artist called 'artistID', then attach that to each link in the ArtistComponent (or the ArtistList as you called it).

Comment: routerLink='artists/artistID' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `app.module.ts` as a new route as

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
    ........,
    {path: 'artists/:artistId', component: ArtistPageComponent }
])
```

***artists-page.component.ts***

```
export class ArtistPageComponent implements onInit{

  artistId:string;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute){
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.artistId = this.route.snapshot.params['artistId'];
  }
}
```

Now you can add a route to *http://app-domain/artists/123* and this will navigate you to artist component with id.

Comment: So, for an artistId, am I giving each artist one in the JSON?

Comment: yes. To identify that particular artist you need to add an identifier like 'id'.